# Why do these two dynamic property assignments collapse into a single value?

Tags: javascript

I may be asking a basic question but I don't know how to clear such a confusion through google search

this below code works fine and count words, so I was trying to understand further

```
var words = chunk.trim().split(' ');
       var counts = {};

   // Count words
   words.forEach(function (word) {
       word = word.trim();

       if (word.length) {
           if (!counts[word]) {
               counts[word] = 0;
           }

           counts[word]++;
       }
   });
```

then why not this below gives me `1,2` . I am expecting `1,2` and its giving me `2,2`

```
var a = function(){
  var a, b;
  var  obj = {}
   obj[a]=1;
   obj[b]=2;

  console.log(obj[a]);
  console.log(obj[b]);
}

var res = a();
```

Comment: Both `a` and `b` are `undefined`, so the only property you're setting on `obj` has the name "undefined", so it gets the last value you set. All object properties are basically strings (except Symbols), so whatever you give for a property gets converted to a string.

Comment: Various ways to test this would be to `console.log()` the values of `a` and `b`, and to log the result of `Object.keys(obj)` to see what keys you gave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't this give me `1,2`? I am expecting `1,2` and it's giving me `2,2`

This is happening because `a == b`; they are both `undefined` because you never assigned them values on the line `var a, b`. When you omit the `=` assignment in `var` declarations, the default value of `undefined` is used instead, meaning that your line becomes `var a = undefined, b = undefined`.

Thus, the second property assignment (`obj[b] = 2`) is actually *overwriting* the first (`obj[a] = 1`). Your `obj` only contains a single key, and after running your code its overall structure looks like:

```
{
  'undefined': 2
}
```

```js
var a = function () {
  var a, b
  var obj = {}
  obj[a] = 1
  obj[b] = 2

  console.log(obj)
}

var res = a()
```

If you want the results you expected, you need to use distinct keys, like the strings `'a'` and `'b'`:

```js
var a = function() {
  var a = 'a', b = 'b'
  var obj = {}
  obj[a] = 1
  obj[b] = 2
  
  console.log(obj)
  console.log(obj[a], obj[b])
}

var res = a()
```

Comment: thanks , so why does `counts[word] = 0;` work . I don't see any line in the whole code like `var word = 'word' ; ` in the word count example ( i posted partial code)

Comment: The [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function automatically passes a `word` value to the callback (here I refer to the `function (word) { ... }`), and it does so once for each element found in the `words` array. Since the `words` array can contain multiple distinct words, key collision does not always occur when doing assignments.

Comment: Why does counts[word] work? The reason is that due to [] notation, JS tries to add a property into counts object after checking that it didn't exist(if condition). So, counts[word] = 0 statement is doing three things, 1) evaluate the value of word variable(if not a string then convert to string), 2) add that evaluation, say it is "abc" as a property to counts object. So it becomes, counts.abc. 3) Set the value of the property to 0 so, counts.abc is equal to 0. Later, its count is incremented if found again.

Answer (score 6):

Because you're only declaring (not assigning) both a and b, and in javascript a not assigned variable is implicitely `undefined`.

you're essentially referring to `obj[undefined]` twice

```
var a,b; //here both the variables are undefined

obj[a]=1; 
obj[b]=2; //you're overriding the variable


console.log(obj[a]); //2
console.log(obj[b]); //2
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say obj[a], javascript tries to create a property on obj with the value in a. Since value in a is undefined, the string representation is "undefined" and hence a property undefined is created on obj.
Since b also happens to have undefined value, you are essentially writing 2 onto the same property undefined.

Hence you get 2 both the times.
Actually if you log obj and see the value in console, you would see:

```
Object {undefined: 2}
undefined:2
```